# How to price forward starting European call option

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, monte-carlo

I have to price a European call option under the Heston model. I have been given a characteristic function (corresponding to the heston model and forward starting call option). I have no idea what to do with this characteristic function and I do not know what Matlab package to solve this with. I have downloaded CFHtoolbox, but can not find a solution there
Thanks a lot, because I am stuck with this problem for 2 weeks now.

Comment: This might have a better chance of finding an answer on [quant.SE].

Comment: See http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/mf/users/oosterle/oosterlee/ng.pdf for details, especially Lemma 3, section 5.3